# Finding the shortest vector from a point to a truncated cone in 3D

Tags: linear-algebra, computational-geometry, game-development

I am trying to understand a certain implementation of calculating the shortest vector between a point and a truncated cone in 3D. The original idea is introduced in [this paper](https://gamma.cs.unc.edu/ORCA/publications/ORCA.pdf).

So if we have two spherical objects: Object A with radius rA, position pA and velocity vA and Object B with radius rB, position pB and velocity vB, then we can represent this in a simpler way calculating the relative position and relative velocity and assuming that object A is a point and the radius of object B is  rA + rB.

In 2D, this will look like doing the transformation from figure (a) to figure (b) where tau is just a scalar factor:
[image]
A

The 3D figure is similar but instead of circles, we have spheres.

Now, if the relative velocity vector lies in the grayed truncated cone, we should find the  vector **u** which is the smallest change to the relative velocity **V** to move it to the circumference of the cone as depicted in the following figure (note: **P** is the relative position):
[image]

This has two cases:

1. If the relative velocity is below the center of the cut-off circle (below the dashed blue line). In this case **u** will be on the cut-off circle (the smaller circle).
2. The second case, which I don't understand how it is calculated, is when the relative velocity is above the center of the small circle(sphere), in this case  **u**will be projected on the tangents of the cone. The intersection of the plane represented by **P** and **V** vectors and the big sphere is a circle that **u** will lie on.

   ```
       const Vector3 relativePosition = other->position_ - position_;
       const Vector3 relativeVelocity = velocity_ - other->velocity_;
       const float distSq = absSq(relativePosition);
       const float combinedRadius = radius_ + other->radius_;
       const float combinedRadiusSq = sqr(combinedRadius);

       Plane plane;
       Vector3 u;

       if (distSq > combinedRadiusSq) {
           /* No collision. */
           const Vector3 w = relativeVelocity - tau * relativePosition;
           /* Vector from cutoff center to relative velocity. */
           const float wLengthSq = absSq(w);

           const float dotProduct = w * relativePosition;

           if (dotProduct < 0.0f && sqr(dotProduct) > combinedRadiusSq * wLengthSq) {
               /* Project on cut-off circle. */
               const float wLength = std::sqrt(wLengthSq);
               const Vector3 unitW = w / wLength;

               plane.normal = unitW;
               u = (combinedRadius * tau - wLength) * unitW;
           }
           else {
               **/* Project on cone. I Don't understand this! */


               const float a = distSq;
               const float b = relativePosition * relativeVelocity;
               const float c = absSq(relativeVelocity) - absSq(cross(relativePosition, relativeVelocity)) / (distSq - combinedRadiusSq);
               const float t = (b + std::sqrt(sqr(b) - a * c)) / a;
               const Vector3 ww = relativeVelocity - t * relativePosition;
               const float wwLength = abs(ww);
               const Vector3 unitWW = ww / wwLength;
               plane.normal = unitWW;
               u = (combinedRadius * t - wwLength) * unitWW;**
           }
       }
   ```

I know in the end we need to find **t** (as in the code) to scale **P**. However, I don't understand how the cross product is utilized here and what does the quadratic equation that we are trying to solve represent.

This function can be found [here](https://github.com/snape/RVO2-3D/blob/bfc048670a4e85066e86a1f923d8ea92e3add3b2/src/Agent.cpp#L119).

Comment: Dot-product is usually used in 3D to test for alignment.  I believe `1 = colinear`, `0 = perpendicular`, and `-1 is colinear` in the other direction.  Cross-product would find the normals, at a 90-degree of that, for reflected rays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

…Though I do not understand how the `collision avoidance` model works, but it seems that the relevant equation can be obtained by considering some angles around the axis.

[image: Geometry and some math expressions to obtain quadratic equation for new velocity calculation in three dimensional reciprocal collision avoidance model.]

By the way, it looks like a pure math problem which is not suitable for SO. [Mathematics Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/) might be better place if you'd like to ask this kind of question.

### Appendix : Another approach

To make the problem/answer a little bit more SO-conscious, I'd like to think about possibility of another coding approach. Since we can use a lot of math-functions (e.g. `asin()`, `sqrt()`) without hesitation in actual programs, it's also possible to calculate the crossing point without `quadratic equation` by utilizing math functions and `vector algebra`, as follows .

```
/* Project on cone. */
const float sin_phi = combinedRadius / std::sqrt(distSq);
const float cos_phi = std::cos(std::asin(sin_phi));

Vector3 E_axial = normalize(relativePosition);
Vector3 E_inplane = normalize(cross(cross(relativePosition, relativeVelocity), E_axial));

Vector3 E_dir = E_axial * cos_phi + E_inplane * sin_phi;

// Based on math: (s * E_dir - relativeVelocity) * E_dir = 0
const float s = relativeVelocity * E_dir;

u = s * E_dir - relativeVelocity;
plane.normal = -normalize(u);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you elaborate on the if statement that checks if w should be projected on the cone or on the cut-off circle? I mean this:
if (dotProduct < 0.0f && sqr(dotProduct) > combinedRadiusSq * wLengthSq)
I understand the dotProduct part. However, I do not understand the geometry behind the second condition.

Comment: The cut off boundary is shown with the dashed line in the figure. Consider the condition `w` points outside of the cut-off cone. `dotProduct = sqrt(wLengthSq) * |P| * cos(psi)` and `|P| * cos(pi/2 - phi) = combinedRadius` then `cos(psi)^2 > cos(pi/2 - phi)^2`